Spy assertion seem incorrect when used inside a setInterval
Using jest 26.6.3, I cannot make the second test here working fine. If I add logs, I can see the callback being called....
export class MyClass {
  constructor() {}

  public foo() {
    console.log("foo");
  }
}

And the test
import { MyClass } from "./MyClass";

jest.mock("./MyClass");
jest.useFakeTimers();

describe("MyClass", () => {
  let myObject: MyClass = new MyClass();

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it("works", () => {
    const fooSpy = jest.spyOn(myObject, "foo");

    myObject.foo();
    expect(fooSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it("does not work", async (done) => {
    const fooSpy = jest.spyOn(myObject, "foo");
    const callback = () => {
      myObject.foo();
    };

    // Call the callback inside setInterval
    const intervalId = setInterval(callback, 1000);
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
    // I also tried jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();

    expect(fooSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // This will fail
    done();
  });
});

Is it a jest bug or am I doing something wrong?

Turned out the solution is this
 beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    jest.useRealTimers();
    jest.useFakeTimers('modern'); // legacy won't work

  });

So definitely sounds like a jest bug
